# How do I need to configure Eclipse to create a C++ program?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, toolchain

I installed Eclipse for C/C++ Developers.
After installing it I also installed PyDev.

I managed to create a C++ project (The Hello World project that comes with it). But I cannot compile/run it.

When I created the project there was nothing in the toolchain list. So I think I will need to install a toolchain. But I cannot find anything. I need someone to help me with this please.

I am using 64 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No compiler, no executable.

Check [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

This is one of the first results i got in google for eclipse and mingw:

http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp

Answer (score 0):

You need to install not only Eclipse CDT, but also a C/C++ compiler for Windows, like minGW.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing TDM-GCC from http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/ . This should have you up and going with a compatible GCC setup under Windows in a snap.